# Fit a table without changing the font size

Tags: tables

I have large tables and they tend to no fit within the page so i used `{adjustbox}{width=1.0\textwidth}` but this make the font extreemly small.

Is there a way that i can fit the table without changining the font size?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.0\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{|llll|}
\hline 
Item & Manufacturer & Catalogue number & Use/Purpose \\ 
\hline \hline 
DMEM Dulbecco's Modified Eagle Medium & Life Technologies  & 41965-039
 & Maintain cultured RBL-2H3 cells  \\ 
\hline 
Penicillin-streptomycin
 & Life Technologies  & 15140-122 & Supplement for cell culture medium \\ 
\hline 

\hline\end{tabular} 


\label{tab}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Table to test captions and labels}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you aware of the `p` column type?

Comment: I just started using Latex few days agog so not really but will look it up.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment and the `X` column type (both provided by the [tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package) for the first and fourth columns.

The `tabularx` environment takes as one of its arguments the desired width of the environment; I would choose `\textwidth`, i.e., let the table occupy the full width of the textblock. The `X` column type (and the derived type `L` used in the example below) allow for automatic line breaks, while relieving the writer (you!) of the chore of having to compute the exact column widths.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
%%%\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]

\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.0\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|llll|}
\hline 
Item & Manufacturer & Catalogue number & Use/Purpose \\ 
\hline \hline 
DMEM Dulbecco's Modified Eagle Medium & Life Technologies  & 41965-039
 & Maintain cultured RBL-2H3 cells  \\ 
\hline 
Penicillin-streptomycin
 & Life Technologies  & 15140-122 & Supplement for cell culture medium \\ 
\hline \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}

\caption{before: tabular, ``l'' columns, adjustbox} \label{tab1}

\end{table}
%%%\end{center}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LllL@{}}
\toprule
Item & Manufacturer & Catalogue  & Use/Purpose \\
& & Number & \\ 
\midrule 
DMEM Dulbecco's Modified Eagle Medium & Life Technologies  & 41965-039 & Maintain cultured RBL-2H3 cells  \\
\addlinespace 
Penicillin-streptomycin
 & Life Technologies  & 15140-122 & Supplement for cell culture medium \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 

\caption{after: tabularx, ``L'' columns, booktabs-based lines}\label{tab2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One problem here. If the table is too long it goes out of the lower border of the page. Is there a way to make it continue to the next page?

Comment: @Alswied - You may have to switch from a `table`/`tabularx` combined environment to a `longtable` environment. Please search this site for any number of postings on how to set up and use `longtable` environments, as well as postings that discuss how to combine `tabularx` and `longtable` environments. If there's a specific issue with your table that's not addressed in these postings, feel free to post a new query.