# Large table to be inserted in document with normal font size

Tags: tables

In LaTeX when I insert a table in my document, the font size in table got very small as compare to the normal font of document. Definitely Table is large in width as well as in length. How I can insert large tables with normal font size, as it used to be in remaining document?

Thanks

Here is my document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    12pt, 
    twoside, 
    openright, 
    cleardoublepage=empty, 
    numbers=noenddot, 
    appendixprefix, 
    BCOR1.5cm, 
    bibliography=totoc 
    ]{scrbook}
```

here is how I insert table

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
```

Comment: Welcome to site! In normal circumstance this newer happen. That with can help you you should show as (in small complete document starting with `\documnetclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` with only necessary packages in document's preamble) what you doing with table.

Comment: The font size in a table changes only if you (or a macro) insert(s) commands to change it. Could you post an example of what happens?

Comment: This is not ordinary behaviour. How are you 'inserting' this table? Please could you provide us with an [MWE (Minimal Working Example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show us what you're doing?

Comment: OP, you appear to have more than one account. It would really help you to use the original account/get the two accounts merged, so that you can edit your own posts, accept answers, reply to comments and generally interact with the site properly

Comment: Please, merge your code fragments to one complete MWE. Change of table's font size is caused by use of `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%`. Avoid it!

Comment: It looks very much like your table is too big to fit on the page. So to solve that problem, you've not unreasonably used `\resizebox` to - well - resize it. This will, of course, shrink the contents of your table! What you need to do is modify the design of your table or find another way to make it fit - such as putting it on its own landscape page (this may not be an idea solution for you) - we can't really help you do that unless you show us your table

Comment: You can find various suggestions for dealing with large tables in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Doesn’t [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245853/69818) help you to solve your issue?  If so, why?  (Note that the linked question was one of those that TeX.SX’s automatic interface suggested as “Related”)‚