# Large table cannot be inserted in document with normal font size

Tags: tables

In LaTeX when I insert a table in my document, the font size in table gets very small compared to the normal font of document. Definitely Table is large in width as well as in length. How I can insert large tables with normal font size, as it used to be in remaining document?

Thanks

Here is my document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, cleardoublepage=empty, numbers=noenddot, appendixprefix, BCOR1.5cm, bibliography=totoc ]{scrbook}
```

here is how I insert table

```
\begin{table}[h!] \centering \caption{My caption} \label{my-label} \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Normally, you should never use `\resizebox` for tables.  That said , if you don't post (part of) the real table, it's hard to help. Probably, you should modify the table layout design.

Comment: Using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!` on text is just specifying you want arbitrarily small, inconsistent font sizes. If you do not want that don't use `\resizebox`. Also don't use `[h!]` it usually generates a warning that it has been changed to `[h!t]` but `[htp]` would be a more reasonable option.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.  Even [your previous, almost identical question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338686/69818) was essentially a duplicate, and you have already been referred to other similar questions where you can find answers that address your issue.